# How to release alloced object that has to be returned from method

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

```
-(NSArray*)getSomeStuff {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Add some objects to array
    return array;
}
```

I alloced that array, so I have to release it at some point. However, how do I release it if I need it until I return it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `autorelease` :

```
return [array autorelease];
```

It will be released later, but the caller might `retain` it to take ownership.

Alternatively, you could use the `array` class method :

```
-(NSArray*)getSomeStuff {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    //...
    return array;
}
```